# What files Cassandra store replicas?

Tags: cassandra

I know Cassandra stores data on keyspace-table-Data.db files, but not sure if the replicas stored on a particular node are also stored on the same file, for example having nodes "A", "B" and "C" and having replication factor of 3 I would expect "A" node to store its own data on Data.db file but not sure if it will store replicas for node "B" and "C" on the same file.

Thanks

Alfonso

Answer (score 2):

Confusing question.

> for example having nodes "A", "B" and "C" and having replication factor of 3 I would expect "A" node to store its own data on Data.db file but not sure if it will store replicas for node "B" and "C" on the same file.

If you have 3 nodes A, B and C and if the replication factor = 3, then all data are replicated 3 times. It means node A stores all the data, same thing for node B and C.

About the keyspace-table-Data.db files, it's the internal storage engine of Cassandra, you may have 1 to N of those file on each node, it doesn't matter. The only thing guaranteed is that every time you insert/update/delete data, the request is sent to all 3 nodes.

Comment: doanduyhai my question is if the data for the replicas is also stored on the same Data.db files. Thanks

Comment: You can have 3 data files on node A, 5 on node B and 1 on node C. It does not matter. The only guarantee is that those 3 nodes normally contains all the data you have